# Workflow foundation 4 receives out-of-order requests and fails with key xx was not associated to an instance

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflowservice

I have a long running workflow service which uses correlation. The client of this service sends two requests in rapid succession. The message pattern for all receive activities is one-way. The binding type is basicHttp. The first request initiates the workflow and the second request performs a specific action correlated to the initial request. In order to insure that messages arrive in order I force the client to sleep for a set time to allow workflow to initiate a request and establish a correlation key. Most of the time requests to the service are handled successfully. Sometimes workflow fails with the message

> "The execution of an InstancePersistenceCommand was interrupted
>   because the instance key 'xx' was not associated to an instance. This
>   can occur because the instance or key has been cleaned up, or because
>   the key is invalid. The key may be invalid if the message it was
>   generated from was sent at the wrong time or contained incorrect
>   correlation data."

The service is hosted in IIS and is currently running on one server. I have one Receive activity that is marked with CanCreateInstance. This activity initiates the workflow then other receive activities, that are inside of a pick activity, respond to a service call. After the initial receive activity as well as after each of the other receives I have an activity called *PromoteValue* which promotes a property through a promoted property participant. The configuration for the persistence details of this service are *timeToPersist="00:01:00" timeToUnload="00:00:00" hostLockRenewalPeriod="00:00:30*

Do I need to set the service to use AllowBufferedReceive and use a channel that supports ReceiveContext? Should I use two-way messaging instead of one way therefore blocking the client until the workflow can finish with the initial request. Using a sleep between calls to the workflow in the client is not desirable but it prevents the error from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody still encounters this issue.
I had couple of workflows up and running and everything working fine, but somehow in new one I created I missed one step and couldn't figure out why I was getting instance not associated msg.

just double check **6f** from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff432975%28v=vs.100%29.aspx